# Sliding pane layout with 3 panels android

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

I got struggle with `SlidingPaneLayout`. I'm trying to create activity with 3 panels like is shown on image:
[image]

The case is that I want to panel 2 was visible by default, and when user swipe from left to right should open panel 1 and when swipe from right to left panel 3. 
When I add views to `SlidingPaneLayout` the last added is visible by default. Is any way to set which view should be starting view? 
Here's my layout xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/side_menu_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/oliveGreen">
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

At this configuration `rightDrawer` is show as starting view. I want to show `LinearLayout` and set `rightDrawr` on the right side of it. 
I hope I made that clear and I would appreciate for any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set your custom adapter and define it there.
https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android/tree/master/SlidingPaneLayout/src/com/survivingwithandroid/slidingpanelayout/adapter

Answer (score 0):

**edit:**

I've just re-read the docs for `SlidingPaneLayout`, and it seems that it's meant for only 2 views.

You might try to fake this layout by using a `ViewPager` and use the [`float getPageWidth(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getPageWidth(int)) from the adapter to make pages 0 and 2 smaller. Not sure if that will fit your requirements.

Besides that the only thing you could do is to check the [SlidingPaneLayout source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.java) and modify it to make it work with `left/right` gravity like the drawer does.

**original answer**

not sure I understand your problem, maybe you expect it to behave differently.

You just use `gravity` to tell which side the panels will be:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/side_menu_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <View android:gravity="left" />
   <View android:gravity="right />
   <View  /> << that's the one always visible.

</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

like this.

Comment: Setting gravity doesn't change a thing.

Comment: did u meant to use the DrawerLayout?? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html

Comment: DrawerLayout doesn't fit my requirements. It has to be SlidingPaneLayout.

Comment: @mlethys please check my edited answer. It does not really solve your problem, but point some discussions. Good luck.